# iOS Google Maps SDK Caching

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

Does anyone now for how long does the iOS Google Maps SDK caches some of the map information? I have done the following test:

1. [Online] Zoom in to a location
2. Kill the app and turn off the internet
3. [Offline] Go back to the app

Only that location that I have zoomed in is still available, my question is, for how long does this happen and if there is a limit on the amount of places that can have an "automatic" cache like this?